# Scheme macros with 2 params

Tags: macros, scheme

Can I define macro that will get one param from left and one from right part of macro? I want to write some kind of this in my programs:

```
(test = 10)
```

to define new variables
I tried to write that macro:

```
(define-syntax = 
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((a _ b)
     (define a b))))
```

But I've got error "bad syntax in: ="

Comment: This probably depends in part on what Scheme implementation you're using. What Scheme implementation are you using?

Comment: Also, the word for this is "infix", as in: "I want to define an infix operator as a macro". You may have more luck searching in this way.

Comment: Even with macros the operator comes first. In the macro `=` has to be the first element so you cannot make lisp infix and strange like Algol like that

Answer (score -1):

Since the form is determined by the first element you'd have problems with `test` not being bound.

The right way is this:

```
(= test 10)
```

You write the macro like this:

```
(define-syntax = 
  (syntax-rules () 
    ((_ a b) (define a b))))
```

There you go. Without horrible infix syntax.